# How to change lower case to upper case char?

Tags: c++, uppercase, lowercase

How do I change a `lower case` char to an upper chase char without having to use  functions like `isdigit`, `isupper`, `toupper`, `isalnum`, `isalpha`, or without having to add or subtract the number 32.  Also I am supposed to use it in the while loop.

> For example: If I type the letter **b** into the .exe, it should send
>   me a message that says "Remember that proper nouns starts with capital
>   and you should've typed '**B**' "

[image]

Comment: `if (b) return B`

Comment: Is there a way I can do this with all the characters included? Instead of having to do it one by one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lower case to upper case without toupper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25063998/lower-case-to-upper-case-without-toupper)

Answer (score 2):

If your platform has [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character set, then you can use XOR to achieve this.

```
char c = 'a';
c ^= 32; // c will now contain 'A'
```

This is possible because of the way ASCII values have been chosen. The difference between the decimal values of small and capital letters of the English alphabet is exactly 32.

If your platform has [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) character set, then you can do

```
char c = 'a';
c ^= 64; // c will now contain 'A'
```

It works because of the same reason mentioned above, only this time the difference is 64 instead of 32.

Answer (score 1):

You might use this

```
 char c = 'A' (to lower case )
 c = c | 32   (TRY THIS..)
 c &= ~32     (as suggested by jejo)
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/case-conversion-lower-upper-vice-versa-string-using-bitwise-operators-cc/

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/toggle-case-string-using-bitwise-operators/

Comment: You should mention that this works for characters encoded ASCII, which is quite common, but it is not a general solution.